# In React JS, How to convert numbers into comma seperated values on keyup event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, numbers

In react Js, Actually I have a big form which has lot of text fields to calculate number, so I want to create a global function to convert numbers into comma seperated values, also need to prevent user to type Alphabets as well.

**Format number function:**

```
format_number(number, prefix, thousand_separator, decimal_separator) {
  let thousand_separator = thousand_separator || ',';
  let decimal_separator = decimal_separator || '.';
  let regex     = new RegExp('[^' + decimal_separator + '\\d]', 'g');
  let number_string = number.replace(regex, '').toString();
  let split   = number_string.split(decimal_separator);
  let rest    = split[0].length % 3;
  let result      = split[0].substr(0, rest);
  let thousands = split[0].substr(rest).match(/\d{3}/g);

  if (thousands) {
      separator = rest ? thousand_separator : '';
      result += separator + thousands.join(thousand_separator);
  }
  let result = split[1] != undefined ? result + decimal_separator + split[1] : result;
  return prefix == undefined ? result : (result ? prefix + result : '');
  }
```

**Constructor:**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        monthlyIncome: '',
        otherMonthlyIncome: '',
    }
    this.format_number = this.format_number.bind(this);
}
```

**Bootstrap form:**

```
<h4>Sources of Income</h4>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <label>Monthly Income (AED / Month)</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.monthlyIncome} id={'monthlyIncome'} onChange={this.format_number}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <label>Other Monthly Income (AED / Month)</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.otherMonthlyIncome} id={'otherMonthlyIncome'} onChange={this.format_number}/>
                    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please make an example of what's the desired output given an example input?

Comment: I updated the description, please check

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
const format_number = function (number, prefix, thousand_separator, decimal_separator) {
    thousand_separator = thousand_separator || ',';
    decimal_separator = decimal_separator || '.';
    const regex = new RegExp('[^' + decimal_separator + '\\d]', 'g');
    let number_string = number.toString().replace(regex, '').toString();
    let split = number_string.split(decimal_separator);
    const thousands = split[0].toString()
            .split('')  // split the integer portion into individual characters
            .reverse()  // reverse the order
            .map((digit, index) => {
                // add a comma after every 3rd character
                return (index > 0 && index % 3 === 0) ? digit + ',' : digit;
            })
            .reverse()  // put it back into the original order
            .join('');  // and make it a string again

    let result = split[1] != undefined ? thousands + decimal_separator + split[1] : thousands;
    return prefix == undefined ? result : (result ? prefix + result : '');
}

console.log(format_number(1.02, '$'));
console.log(format_number(1000.02, '%', ':'));
console.log(format_number(1000000.02));

const tests = [
    1,
    10,
    100,
    1000,
    10000,
    100000,
    1000000,
    10000000,
    100000000,
    1000000000,
    10000000000,
];

console.log(tests.map( num => format_number(num)))
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please update your question with concrete examples of input and output (i.e., input of `1000` and output of `???`).

Comment: Please find the given URL
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/209872/

actually there is a form, I want 2 things as following
1) when user type in anyof the textbox the number convert into comma seperated.
2) In line no 46, I am appending calculation of the boxes in a div block by using javascript "document.getElementbyId", can I apply this by using setState?

Comment: @MuhammadOwais Both of those are possible. See https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/209927/